# Combination of Mobx-state-tree, Mobx-react and RenderProps not updating react component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

This is a complex problem. Hope I manage to explain so everyone can understand the bug

**1) Parent component.**

```
@observer
export class Edit extends React.Component<IProps> {
  article: any

  componentWillMount() {
    const articleId = this.props.routerStore!.routerState.params.id!

    this.article = ArticleModel.create({ id: articleId || null })
    this.article.init()
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.article) {
      return <div>loading...</div>
    }

    return <div className='main-wrapper'>
      <EditArticle article={this.article} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

**2) Child Component**
It uses the `react-beautiful-dnd` to allow drag and drop on the article layout. This library uses RenderProps `(provided: any, snapshot)`

```
@observer
export class EditArticle extends React.Component<IProps> {
  render() {
    return <div className='main-column article-target'>
      <Droppable
        ignoreContainerClipping
        direction={'vertical'}
        droppableId='article'
        key={'article'}
      >
        {(provided: any, snapshot: any) => {
          return <ObservedDragDropContext
              provided={provided}
              snapshot={snapshot}
            >
              {this.props.article.layout.map((el: any, index: number) => {
                return <WithDragable
                  key={getPath(el)}
                  id={getPath(el)}
                  index={index}
                  remove={() => {}}
                >
                  <div className='layout-item'>
                    <Layout key={getPath(el)} item={el} />
                  </div>
                </WithDragable>
              })}
            </ObservedDragDropContext>
        }}
      </Droppable>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Article is a mobx-state-tree model.
This is the init method of the actions property of the model:

```
init() {
  const run = flow(function*() {
    const res = yield getArticle(self.id)
    applySnapshot(self, res)
  })

  run()
},
```

The flow is the following:
1) create the article
2) init the article
3) I expect to see the article updated after I get the response and applySnapshot on the article

But the child component doesn't get rerendered after applySnapshot is run. I checked and applySnapshot runs and the article has the updated values received from backend.

I assume the problem is because I use RenderProps in my child component and this interferes in some way and restricts the component from rerendering.

The tricky bit is that if I add

```
{this.props.article.layout.map((el: any, index: number) =>
  <Layout key={getPath(el)} item={el} />
)}
```

in the child component in the `render` function anywhere, this will fix the problem and the initial component gets updated. So just by rerendering the props, the child component rerenders itself and implicitly fixes my initial bug by rerendering the Drappable and the RenderProps.

**Possible Solution 1:** if I use a different react DND library that is not using RenderProps everything updates as it should. But I don't want to do that because `react-beautiful-dnd` has nice animations and I would need to refactor some of the code.

I haven't been able to understand why the Child component is not rerendered.

Is the Child Component not aware that it depends on the article because I use the `this.props.article` only inside the renderProps?

Can I avoid using the renderProps?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you should use <Observer> from mobx-react library instead @observer. Something like this - <ObservedDragDropContext><Observer render={()=>{ {this.props.article.layout.map .... }}></ObservedDragDropContext>

Comment: This works. Wrapping the map inside an Observer works. But why?
The child class is wrapped itself in a @observer. What is the difference?

Comment: What Mobx version are you using? 4 and earlier are not reacting to nested changes

Comment: version "5.9.4". But @anton62k answer fixed the problem.